# Pontryagin's maximum principle with state constraints at specific points but they are not initial and final points

Tags: optimization

i am solving Pontryagin's Maximum Principle (PMP) but in my case *x(t0)* are fixed instead of *x(tf)*, it is *x(t1)* is fixed where as *t1* is some point which lies between *t0* and *tf*. How can i solve such a problem..should i first solve from to to *t1* and then *t1* to *tf*?but i want to solve it as single intersection? plz guide me

Comment: You'll get a jump condition on the co-state variable at $t_1$, see [Maximum principle for optimal control problems with intermediate constraints by Dmitruk-Kaganovich](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241015840_Maximum_principle_for_optimal_control_problems_with_intermediate_constraints), Theorem 4.